# Click to extand layout to full screen like Neighbourly: Ask Local Questions & Get Answers

Tags: android, animation, layout, expand

I want to make my layout expand to full screen like **Neighbourly: Ask Local Questions & Get Answers** how I can achieve it.

[Image before expand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lIvj.png)

[Image after expand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlOzN.png)

Comment: What so far you have tried or to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Set the theme in AndroidManifest.xml

Make your activity fullscreen